# Uploading multiple files asynchronously without stomping on each other?

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, extjs, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code, I have the files uploading with this code, but almost every time, 2 or more of the files don't succeed because of the same type of error:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ag9mdW5ueS1wYWdlcy1ocmRyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgICKCgw 
404 (No upload session: ag9mdW5ueS1wYWdlcy1ocmRyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgICKCgw)
```

Now here is the thing I need to get a different upload url for every file.
`getUploadURL()` is returning the exact same URL for every call.

*Cache Busting* doesn't help either.

I have tried with the `Ext.TaskManager` and without it with the same results, the error that is posted above on at least 2 of the 10 files I am using to test with.

```
var files = Ext.getDom('select-upload-button-fileInputEl').files;

function uploadFile(url, f) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', f, f.name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        console.log(f.name + " : " + (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 + "%");
    });
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        console.log(f.name + ' Transfer Complete');
    });
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}

function getUploadURL(f) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var url = this.responseText;
        console.log(url);
        var task = Ext.TaskManager.start({
            run: uploadFile(url, f)
        });
    });
    xhr.open('GET', '/upload', true);
    xhr.send()
}


Ext.each(files, function (f) {
    var task = Ext.TaskManager.start({
        run: getUploadURL(f)
    });
});
```

If I change the code to do the `xhr.open('GET', '/upload', false);` and `xhr.open('POST', url, false);`, it works as desired, but I would rather have it asynchronous if possible.

HTML5 only solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following line:

```
xhr.open('POST', url, false);
```

instead of

```
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
```

I would really rather have an asynchronous solution, but right now I just need to get this working.